How to manage nested models in ASP.NET and mongodb
example document of mongo
I have an example model like that but I don't know how to make it recursive because I may have n number of features or cases. For example, I can't create case under child feature or I can't create feature under child feature. I can't use my methods under child feature's child feature, but I can use them in my parent.
https://paste.mod.gg/dtnvlxwutido/0 this is my model structure.
https://paste.mod.gg/bokpwbismsii/0 this is my controller.
https://paste.mod.gg/yoripjuhljra/0// and this is my service.
I tried to make recursive but didn't manage to do it successfully.
https://github.com/ensarerdeve/nested-backend here are the whole codes of my project.
